# IIS Web API Connection Was Reset

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, crash, iis-7.5, sap-business-one-di-api

I've web API hosted on IIS.

I've been getting "Connection Was Reset" on random times as a response to my API Calls. and after several retrial my request gets a proper response

I've checked HTTPERR and found a lot of "Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue" near the time i got Connection Was Reset Response. also i sometimes get App Crash in Event Viewer contains the following:

*Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: w3wp.exe
P2: 8.5.9600.16384
P3: 52157ba0
P4: SAPbobsCOM90.dll
P5: 9.30.190.0
P6: 5c7f4d65
P7: c0000005
P8: 0089a548
P9: 
P10:

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_w3wp.exe_695eddbfadf3c4a0ec181813e91099c0502fcadb_234314c6_7e0a5f90

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 6975c2ef-e9ad-11e9-80ca-00155d0b1f02
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: *

I've managed to export a Dump file from IIS the time the crash happened.
and used windbg and DebugDiag. and found out the exception is System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
but this error makes no sense, since the same request get a proper request after multiple retrials.

Comment: It really depends on the call stack of exception to tell which module/assembly is the culprit and who can help you out.